# Why does my SSH session hang and then close with Broken Pipe?

Tags: linux, ssh

We have a RHEL 6.1 machine that just started exhibiting an issue with ssh. Originally it stopped accepting connections and when we looked at the console we saw it was filled with lines about a tainted kernel.

We rebooted and the ssh client would connect and the banner text would display but the session would go no further (i.e. no prompt). Eventually the session would disconnect and a broken pipe error would appear.

SSH with a command would work (i.e. ssh targetserver "date") as well as scp but that is it.

I have the full output of ssh -vvv and I can share if need be. What could be going on?

Comment: The client's logs aren't going to tell you anything here. "Broken pipe" in this situation just means "the server is not responding". It's the output of the server's kernel logs that would be most useful; all the warnings you see in its console aren't the result of connections breaking, they are the *cause* of connections breaking. (For now, I'm betting on the warnings being "unable to page in /bin/something because the HDD is dying".)

Comment: I do not see anything in dmesg nor in /var/log/messages to indicate that.